# sorting dictionary values with a transformation function

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Given the following dictionary:

```
a = {'foo': {'n': 'one', 'text': 'bla'},
     'bar': {'n': 'two', 'text': 'blah'},
     'baz': {'n': 'three', 'text': 'blabla'}}
```

I want a resulting list that is sorted by the value in `n`:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

given that the values in `n` are constant and known (all of them). So for the sake of the example, only `one`, `two`, and `three` are the allowed values in `n`.

I assume this has to be some combination of `sorted()` on `a.items()` with a transformation lambda function that replaces `one` with 1 and so on, so that the sorted function actually works. But I can't seem to string it together to make it work.

Comment: `sorted(a.keys(), lambda x: a[x]['n'])`

Comment: @BhargavRao Did you not read the second sentence? I want to sort the values from a dictionary *into* a list. You can sort values of anything, this has nothing to do with a dictionary.

Comment: @thkang That doesn't seem to work and also it would sort alphabetically on the values in `n`.

Comment: @mart1n The title was incorrect. I did not go past the title. Will read now. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mention *given that the values in n are constant and known*, you can use a `mapping_dict` for that. The trick is that you need to map each value of your given set in the dictionary. So once you have the mapper ready, using the `sorted` function's `key` parameter, you can use it to map the answer.

```
>>> a = {'foo': {'n': 'one', 'text': 'bla'},
...      'bar': {'n': 'two', 'text': 'blah'},
...      'baz': {'n': 'three', 'text': 'blabla'}}
>>> mapping_dict = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
>>> sorted(a.keys(),key = lambda x: mapping_dict[a[x]['n']])
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand, but

```
a = {'foo': {'n': 'one', 'text': 'bla'},
     'bar': {'n': 'two', 'text': 'blah'},
     'baz': {'n': 'three', 'text': 'blabla'}}


order = ['three', 'one', 'two']

r = sorted(a, key=lambda k: order.index(a[k]['n']))
```